# How do I make a chamfered corner using XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to make a chamfered corner on a custom control for Windows Phone 8. I'd like to achieve something much like the following:

http://jdcard.com/engl3007/arpln02.gif (I cannot post images yet because of my reputation)

I know it's possible to create a rounded corner, but I haven't had much luck at creating a chamfered corner. I'd like the corner to be only on the bottom right. The control should resize according to its contents.

Comment: can you use some control to do your job with animation. http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/

Comment: did you look into [UIElement.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip.aspx)?

Comment: @dkozl I did look into UIElement.Clip. Do you happen to know if there's a way to substract a shape, instead of adding? I figure I'd need to make a rectangle with a triangle cut out, but I have a hard time writing shapes with dimensions based on other shapes' dimensions.

Comment: @Mohit I only need a static folded corner effect, so animating the whole control wouldn't be necessary. Thanks though, I'll keep it in mind! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a control which puts an image with the desired effect in the background and aligned to the appropriate corner?

Comment: There're multiple of such controls on a scrollpanel, and the background should be visible. Unfortunately it's an image and not a filled colour!

Comment: @ThomasBaart Make a UserControl if you need to use it multiple times. Use transparency if you want to see the background through it. What problem is there with using an image? It sounds like a mock-up of what you're trying to achieve would help us to help you.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding a Grid with two columns beneath everything else, the first column with width="*", and the second with width="15". I added a rectangle that stretched all across and filled all available space, and drew a Polygon in the shape of a triangle to give the effect. Simpler than I thought!